# Implementation of ISupportErrorInfo - what does it mean?

Tags: com, error-handling

What does the `ISupportErrorInfo` interface mean? I'm at a bit of a loss to understand it. From MSDN:

> This interface ensures that error
>   information can be propagated up the
>   call chain correctly. Automation
>   objects that use the error handling
>   interfaces must implement
>   ISupportErrorInfo.
>
> This method indicates whether or not
>   an interface supports the IErrorInfo
>   interface.

```
HRESULT InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo(
  REFIID riid
);
```

What does it mean to return S_OK in `InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo`? Should you return S_OK for all interfaces? Just some?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My understanding of it (based on some related MSDN pages) is that by implementing `ISupportErrorInfo`, you are indicating that one or more interfaces on your class returns error information by calling `SetErrorInfo`, as opposed to just returning a failure `HRESULT`.

To that end, your implementation of `ISuportErrorInfo::InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo` should return `S_OK` only for those interfaces on your class that actually use `SetErrorInfo` to return error information to the caller, and **only** those interfaces.

For example, say you have a class that implements an interface you wrote called `IFoo` that has a `DoSomething` method. If someone else creates an instance of your class and calls `IFoo::DoSomething`, they are supposed to do the following if `DoSomething` returns a failure `HRESULT` (paraphrasing from various MSDN pages, but I started from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221510.aspx):

- Call `QueryInterface` on the `IFoo` pointer to get the `ISupportErrorInfo` interface for the object that is implementing `IFoo`
- If the called object doesn't implement `ISupportErrorInfo`,
  then the caller will have
  to handle the error based on the
  `HRESULT` value, or pass it up the call stack.
- If the called object does implement `ISupportErrorInfo`, then the caller should call `ISupportErrorInfo::InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo`, passing in a `REFIID` for the interface that returned the error. In this case, the `DoSomething` method of the `IFoo` interface returned an error, so you would pass `REFIID_IFoo` (assuming it's defined) to `InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo`.
- If `InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo`
  returns `S_OK`, then the caller
  knows at this point that it can
  retrieve more detailed information
  about the error by calling
  `GetErrorInfo`. If `InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo` returns `S_FALSE`, the caller can assume the called interface doesn't supply detailed error information, and will have to rely on the returned HRESULT to figure out what happened.

The reason for this somewhat confusing/convoluted error-handling API seems to be for flexibility (as far I as I can tell anyway. This *is* COM after all ;). With this design, a class can support multiple interfaces, but not every interface is required to use `SetErrorInfo` to return error information from its methods. You can have certain, select interfaces on your class return detailed error information via `SetErrorInfo`, while other interfaces can continue to use normal `HRESULT`s to indicate errors.

In summary, the `ISupportErrorInfo` interface is a way to inform the calling code that at least one of the interfaces your class implements can return detailed error information, and the `InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo` method tells the caller whether a given interface is one of those interfaces. If so, then the caller can retrieve the detailed error information by calling `GetErrorInfo`.

Comment: "If the called object does implement ISupportErrorInfo, then the caller is supposed to QueryInterface for a ISupportErrorInfo" This is probably an error, because the caller just DID that call before to determine if this interface is supported in the first place? Shouldn't the caller then call `ISupportErrorInfo::InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo` directly without having to call QI a 2nd time?

Comment: @FelixDombek I agree. I edited the post to remove the redundant `QueryInterface` call.