# Implementing ISupportErrorInfo on a C# object exposed to COM

Tags: .net, asp-classic, error-handling, com-interop

I'm writing a COM object in C# and I'd like to raise errors to vba/asp client software using the mechanism it understands - the Err object.

In good ol' days that would have meant implementing ISupportErrorInfo on the COM object but I can't find any information about how to implement that interface in a C# object.

Can anybody help?

thanks!

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172942/implementation-of-isupporterrorinfo-what-does-it-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simulate this by throwing a custom exception from the Managed code.  All CCW's automatically implement ISupportErrorInfo ([Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/111chfb8.aspx)) and understand how to return error information for a thrown exception.

All you need to do is create a custom exception (if a current one does not suite you) and provide the appropriate HResult by setting the base Exception.HResult member.