# When calling managed code called from unmanaged code, is it possible to inspect the exception object?

Tags: exception, interop

Working with COM interop, I can call a managed function from within unmanaged code.
But, this only gives me the HRESULT for the exception, in case a managed exception is thrown.

Is there anyway to further inspect the exception from the unmanaged code? For example, to look at the message contained in the exception object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QueryInterface the managed object for [ISupportErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221083.aspx) to get additional information.

A similar question: [Implementing ISupportErrorInfo on a C# object exposed to COM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715073/implementing-isupporterrorinfo-on-a-c-object-exposed-to-com)